# Using Firebase Authentication with Unity on standalone game

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make a cross platform game using Firebase with Firebase Unity SDK(now Version 1.1.1).
I would like to use Firebase realtime database.
I know that SDK does not correspond to standalone game and on UnityEditor, but it works without problems on standalone game limited realtime database. However, Authentication can not be used in same situation so it is necessary to open permission rules:

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```

But it is never realistic to use actually.

Do you have good ideas to use Firebase Authentication with Unity3D on standalone game?
Or does that SDK have been planned to correspond to standalone game?
Firebase is very powerful, but I regret that it can not unify all the circumstances.

Comment: Standalone builds aren't currently supported by firebase-unity which is a real pain. I'd suggest getting in touch with firebase via the google groups or whatever to register your interest in standalone support.

Comment: It can not check work on the UnityEditor, and It can not choose Firebase on Standalone game...   It seems that many user should feel inconvenience:(  Even just showing whether Google will be going to correspond this, we could start work around Firebase. I send my opinion to support, I want users who are in this trouble to poke Google likewise.

Comment: I found I could get database working by setting the build target for standalone to x86_64. I haven't tried the authentication module. I already asked for an update on the firebase google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/XLaACoVjysc/1HI6E8zABAAJ